# linkbutton doesn't work for updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have set of link buttons outside update panel but when click any one of them they donot work at all , when i set the postbackUrl they make full postback

my source code:

`<asp:Panel ID="pnl_viewImages" runat="server">`

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_viewImages" runat="server" style="texalign: left" 
    Text="view images :"></asp:Label>
<br />
<br />
<br />

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%" class ="Alternating">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl_image" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ListView ID="lv_showImages" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Image ID="img_showNewsImage0" runat="server" Height="300px" 
                                ImageUrl='<%# "RetreiveImage.ashx" %>' Width="413px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtn_first" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtn_last" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtn_next" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtn_previous" EventName="Click" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtn_delete" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_first" runat="server" onclick="lbtn_first_Click">first</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_previous" runat="server" onclick="lbtn_first_Click">&lt;&lt;</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_next" runat="server" onclick="lbtn_first_Click" 
                >&gt;&gt;</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_last" runat="server" onclick="lbtn_first_Click">last</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_delete" runat="server" onclick="lbtn_first_Click">delete</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
```

i tried to remove the table but in vain it does not work also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the LinkButtons in the UpdatePanel or put them in their own UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing a ScriptManger defined before your update panel such as

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat ="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

I think that is probably causing your problem.

Controls outside of the panel can invoke a partial postback.

Paul

Comment: I'm not to sure what the problem could be as I've never used any telerik controls.  You could try posting your question in their forums if you have not already.  I have done what you're trying to do multiple times with a standard script manager and an update panel with the trigger defined as you have.  Couple of other things to check:  In you web.config do you xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" as this will disable script managers and do you have a httpModule node for the ScriptModule type = System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions?  Good luck and sorry couldn't be mroe help.

Comment: I use generic handler to bind on the image in the listview , and the handler write stream , is there any conflicts between AJAX concept and streaming or generic handler

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand, I do know that Response.Write will break an standard Ajax Partial Postback but that doesn't explain why your page is always fully posting back.

Comment: Could you remove the reference to the ashx file and see if your page partially post backs?